# Gulp Less task not doing anything

Tags: gulp, less

I have a Less task in my Gulp script, but it's not working like it should:

**1**
It's supposed to compile less files and move them to 'build/css' folder. But for some reason it doesn't work. Why?

**2**
I tried to use gulp-util to log errors. It cathes wrong file name in imported less files. But it does not detect undefined classes. And it does not indicate why files are not compiled.

Any hints is much appreciated!

**gulpfile.js**

```
var gulp           = require("gulp"),
    util           = require('gulp-util'),
    minifyHTML     = require("gulp-minify-html"),
    concat         = require("gulp-concat"),
    uglify         = require("gulp-uglify"),
    cssmin         = require("gulp-cssmin"),
    uncss          = require("gulp-uncss"),
    imagemin       = require("gulp-imagemin"),
    sourcemaps     = require("gulp-sourcemaps"),
    inject         = require("gulp-inject"),
    less           = require("gulp-less"),
    filter         = require("gulp-filter"),
    glob           = require("glob"),
    browserSync    = require("browser-sync"),
    LessPluginAutoPrefix = require('less-plugin-autoprefix'),
    autoprefix     = new LessPluginAutoPrefix({
        browsers: ["last 2 versions"]
    });

var config = {
    paths: {
        html: {
            src:  "src/**/*.html",
            dest: "build"
        },
        javascript: {
            src:  ["src/js/**/*.js"],
            dest: "build/js"
        },
        css: {
            src: ["src/css/**/*.css"],
            dest: "build/css"
        },
        less: {
            src: ["src/less/**/*.less", "!src/less/includes/**"],
            dest: "build/css"
        },
        images: {
            src: ["src/images/**/*.jpg", "src/images/**/*.jpeg", "src/images/**/*.png"],
            dest: "build/images"
        },
        audio: {
            src: "src/audio/**/*.mp3",
            dest: "build/audio"
        }
    }
};

gulp.task("html", function(){
    return gulp.src(config.paths.html.src)
        .pipe(minifyHTML())
        .pipe(gulp.dest(config.paths.html.dest));
});

gulp.task("scripts", function(){
    return gulp.src(config.paths.javascript.src)
        .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
        .pipe(concat("app.min.js"))
        .pipe(uglify())
        .pipe(sourcemaps.write())
        .pipe(gulp.dest(config.paths.javascript.dest));
});

gulp.task("css", function(){
    return gulp.src(config.paths.css.src)
        .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
        .pipe(cssmin())
        .pipe(sourcemaps.write("."))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(config.paths.css.dest))
        .pipe(browserSync.reload({stream: true}));
});

gulp.task("less", function(){
    return gulp.src(config.paths.less.src)
        .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
        .pipe(less({
            paths: ["node_modules/bootstrap/less"],
            plugins: [autoprefix]
        }))
        .pipe(uncss({
            html: glob.sync(config.paths.html.src)
        }))
        .pipe(concat("main.min.css"))
        .pipe(sourcemaps.write("."))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(config.paths.less.dest))
        .pipe(filter("**/*.css"))
        .pipe(browserSync.reload({stream: true}));
});

gulp.task("images", function(){
    return gulp.src(config.paths.images.src)
        .pipe(imagemin({
            progressive: true,
            interlaced: true
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(config.paths.images.dest));
});

gulp.task("audio", function() {
    return gulp.src([config.paths.audio.src]).pipe(gulp.dest(config.paths.audio.dest));
});

gulp.task("browser-sync", function() {
    browserSync({
        server: {
            baseDir: "./build"
        }
    });
});

gulp.task("build", ["html", "scripts", "css", "less", "images", "audio"]);

gulp.task("default", ["build", "browser-sync"], function(){
    gulp.watch(config.paths.html.src, ["html", browserSync.reload]);
    gulp.watch(config.paths.javascript.src, ["scripts", browserSync.reload]);
    gulp.watch(config.paths.css.src, ["css"]);
    gulp.watch(config.paths.less.src, ["less"]);
    gulp.watch(config.paths.images.src, ["images", browserSync.reload]);
    gulp.watch(config.paths.audio.src, ["audio", browserSync.reload]);
});
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "ofj-simon-says",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "description": "Click a color sequence",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "bower": "^1.3.12",
    "browser-sync": "^2.14.0",
    "glob": "^7.0.6",
    "gulp": "^3.8.10",
    "gulp-concat": "^2.4.1",
    "gulp-cssmin": "^0.1.6",
    "gulp-filter": "^4.0.0",
    "gulp-imagemin": "^3.0.3",
    "gulp-inject": "^4.1.0",
    "gulp-less": "^3.1.0",
    "gulp-minify-html": "^1.0.6",
    "gulp-sourcemaps": "^1.2.8",
    "gulp-uglify": "^2.0.0",
    "gulp-uncss": "^1.0.6",
    "gulp-util": "^3.0.7",
    "less-plugin-autoprefix": "^1.5.1",
    "main-bower-files": "^2.4.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.7"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be a problem with gulp-uncss plugin. When I remove it, everything works. I tried to update to newest version 1.0.6 but to no avail. I'll have to look more into it more deeply before saying what the problem is. For now I'm removing uncss() from the less task:

```
gulp.task("less", function(){
    return gulp.src(config.paths.less.src)
        .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
        .pipe(less({
            plugins: [autoprefix]
        }).on('error', util.log))
        .pipe(concat('main.min.css'))
        //.pipe(uncss({
        //    html: glob.sync(config.paths.html.src)
        //}))
        .pipe(nano())
        .pipe(sourcemaps.write("."))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(config.paths.less.dest))
        .pipe(browserSync.reload({stream: true}));
});
```